# is there a way to replicate the moveTo method in cocos2d for UIKit?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, uikit

I would rather not change my entire project to cocos2d from UIKit, because all I need from cocos is the moveTo thing, so how can I do this method in UIKit anyone have any ideas?

Comment: i like both answers but i go with bots because has tutorial with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.raywenderlich.com/5478/uiview-animation-tutorial-practical-recipes I found this with a simple google search.

Specifically you will want

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: animations:^{}];
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an entire animation set for UIKit. Here's a link to Apple's Animation docs:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html